# Renaming a file that has a bracket in the file name using power shell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to rename a file that has a bracket in the file name. This does not seem to work because powershell sees [] as special characters and does not know what to do.

I have a folder on my computer c:\test. I want to be able to look through that folder and rename all files or portions of the file. The following code seems to work but if the file has any special characters in it the code fails:

```
Function RenameFiles($FilesToRename,$OldName,$NewName){

    $FileListArray = @()
    Foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $FilesToRename -Force -Recurse  | Where-Object {$_.attributes -notlike "Directory"})
    {
        $FileListArray += ,@($file)
    }

    Foreach($File in $FileListArray)
    {
        IF ($File -match $OldName )
        {
            $File | rename-item -newName {$_ -replace "$OldName", "$NewName" }
        }
    }
}

renamefiles -FilesToRename "c:\test" -OldName "testt2bt" -NewName "test"
```

I did find a similar question: [Replace square bracket using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089028/replace-square-bracket-using-powershell), but I can't understand how to use the answer cause it's just a link explaining the bug:

Comment: Why can't you use the move-item suggestion listed in the answer that you reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for help guys you all helped a lot this is the solution I came up with in the end after reading your reply’s .

I have a folder on my pc called c:\test and it has a file in it called "[abc] testfile [xas].txt" and i want it to be called testfile2.txt

```
Function RenameFiles($FilesToRename,$OldName,$NewName){

$FileListArray = @()
Foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $FilesToRename -Force -Recurse  | Where-Object {$_.attributes -notlike "Directory"})
{
    $FileListArray += ,@($file.name,$file.fullname)
}

Foreach($File in $FileListArray)
{
    IF ($File -match $OldName )
    {
        $FileName = $File[0]
        $FilePath = $File[1]

        $SName = $File[0]  -replace "[^\w\.@-]", " "

        $SName = $SName -creplace '(?m)(?:[ \t]*(\.)|^[ \t]+)[ \t]*', '$1'

        $NewDestination = $FilePath.Substring(0,$FilePath.Length -$FileName.Length)
        $NewNameDestination = "$NewDestination$SName"
        $NewNameDestination | Write-Host

        Move-Item -LiteralPath $file[1] -Destination $NewNameDestination
        $NewNameDestination | rename-item -newName {$_ -replace "$OldName", "$NewName" }

        }
    }
}


renamefiles  -FilesToRename "c:\test" -OldName "testfile" -NewName "testfile2"
```

Answer (score 11):

For multiple files this can be done with one line.

To remove the bracket you should try:

```
get-childitem | ForEach-Object { Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.name $_.name.Replace("[","")}
```

Comment: This worked well for me. Our workplace restricts powershell scripts. I was able to modify this one-liner to remove the first few characters of each file name. Having it in one-line made it easy to give to folks to paste into a powershell window. Thanks for the post!

Answer (score 7):

```
Move-Item -literalpath "D:\[Copy].log" -destination "D:\WithoutBracket.txt"
```

Use the [literalpath](http://ss64.com/ps/move-item.html) switch with the Move-Item cmdlet [instead of using the rename-item cmdlet]

Comment: That will work but how would i dynamically crate a new name with out the brackets if you look at my example it would replace all the files that contain testt2bt in the name with just test. SO i am not sure how to dynamically change the name and remove the brackets

Comment: Sorry, I did not get ? Even by _Move-Item_  [as shown above], you will achieve the dynamic renaming. Did you try that in your sample ?

Answer (score 3):

As far as bracket are concerned, you've got Microsoft official answer in an old [Technet Windows PowerShell Tip of the Week](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730956.aspx).

You can use :

```
Get-ChildItem 'c:\test\``[*``].*'
```