# Error using Import-Csv

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

I'm using PowerShell to import CSV file but get this error:
**Unable to find the specified file.**

The file name is generated automatically by system performance counters collector.
"Oracle_Data_Provider_for_.NET(defaultdomain [10148, 1]).csv"

If I rename file to "Oracle_Data_Provider_for_.NET(defaultdomain 10148, 1).csv" the file opened correctly.

The version of PowerShell is:

```
PS U:\> $PSVersionTable
Name                           Value               
----                           -----               
PSVersion                      4.0                 
WSManStackVersion              3.0                 
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1             
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18444     
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406      
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Any suggestions for how to fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace square bracket using Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089028/replace-square-bracket-using-powershell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets are [wildcard characters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you have literal square brackets in a filename you need to use the [`-LiteralPath`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) parameter:

> **-LiteralPath<String[]>**
>
> Specifies the path to the CSV file to import. Unlike **Path**, the value of the **LiteralPath** parameter is used exactly as it is typed. No characters are interpreted as wildcards. If the path includes escape characters, enclose it in single quotation marks. Single quotation marks tell Windows PowerShell not to interpret any characters as escape sequences.

Example:

```
Import-Csv -LiteralPath "Oracle_Data_Provider_for_.NET(defaultdomain [10148, 1]).csv"
```